# E2E Testing Material-UI Select with Puppeteer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, puppeteer

I'm unable to access dropdown values (`<MenuItem>`) in dropdown on Material-UI `Select` component.

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is following, click on input with `id='x'`, wait for the dropdown to show up (`div` with `ul` and `li`, where each li has `id='y'` prop), select specific one and then click on it.

The dropdown is related to filter...

Note: Using native select is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

You need to trigger first mousedown and then click events on the Material Select element. You can use the following function in your Puppeteer code.

```
const MaterialSelect = async (page, newSelectedValue, cssSelector) => {
    await page.evaluate((newSelectedValue, cssSelector) => {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent("mousedown", true, true);
        var selectNode = document.querySelector(cssSelector);
        selectNode.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].filter(el => el.innerText == newSelectedValue)[0].click();
    }, newSelectedValue, cssSelector);
}
```

Example usage:
"demo-simple-select" is the id I assigned to material-ui Select

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://my-app-site/page');
    await MaterialSelect(page, 'new selected value', '#demo-simple-select');
})();
```

Comment: For the cssSelector, is #demo-simple-select the id you assigned to the material-ui Select?  e.g. 

<Select id='demo-simple-select' ...>

Comment: yes, that is the id I assigned to material-ui Select

Answer (score 0):

A simple one.

Use [expect-puppeteer](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer/tree/master/packages/expect-puppeteer#toClick) npm package to get `onClick` method.

Then Declare:

```
export const MaterialSelect = async (page, cssSelector, newSelectedValue) => {
    await expect(page).toClick(cssSelector);
    await expect(page).toClick(`li[data-value="${newSelectedValue}"]`);
}
```

And use it like:

```
 await MaterialSelect(page, '#demo-simple-select', 'new selected value');
```